# Creating a user-overridable config system in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, angular-promise, angular-services, angular-http

I'm working on a angularJS-based tool for building charts and am wanting to create a user-overridable config system — i.e., default values are loaded from one config file, which are then overridden if another config file exists.

Here's what I have so far:

```
angular.module('axisJSApp')
  .provider('configProvider', function () {
    this.$get = function axisJSConfig($http, $q) {
      var defaultConfig = $http.get('default.config.yaml');
      var userConfig = $http.get('config.yaml');

      return $q.all([defaultConfig, userConfig]).then(function(values){
        var defaultConfigYaml = jsyaml.safeLoad(values[0].data);
        var userConfigYaml = jsyaml.safeLoad(values[1].data);
        return angular.extend(defaultConfigYaml, userConfigYaml);
      });
    };
  });
```

Then in my controller:

```
angular.module('axisJSApp')
  .controller('MainCtrl', function (configProvider, $scope) {
    configProvider.then(function(appConfig){
      console.dir(appConfig); // Config loaded, everything else happens.
    });
  });
```

This all works fine if both default.config.yaml and config.yaml exist. My question is, **how do I cause $q.all() to fail gracefully if `config.yaml` doesn't exist**?

Additionally, is there any way of synchronously loading the config file so I don't have to wrap my entire controller in a `.then()`?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way I can think of to handle the non-existence of `config.yaml` gracefully is:

```
var userConfig = $http.get('config.yaml').then(
    function(response) {
        return response.data;
    },
    function(response) {
        if( response.status === 404 ) {
            response.data = {};
            return response;
        }
        else {
            return $q.reject(response);
        }
    }
);

return $q.all([defaultConfig, userConfig]).... // AS BEFORE
```

So you manually fix the "does not exist" case, by returning an empty object in `response.data` (or anything that suits your needs).

I cannot think of an elegant way to load the config files synchronously; if you are using `ngRoute`, you could use the `resolve` configuration for the route (more [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/provider/$routeProvider)) to feed the controller with the data before it starts.

Comment: That's all super helpful. Using ngRoute is an interesting idea, hadn't considered that. Thank you!